# How to fix the missing order of id in the pandas dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fix one issue with this dataset.
The link is [here](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/10m/).
So, I loaded the dataset this way.

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep='::', names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])
num_of_unique_users = len(df['user_id'].unique())
```

The number of unique user is ***69878***.
If we print out the last rows of the dataset.
We can see that the user id is above 69878.
There are missing user id in this case.
Same case for movie id. There is an exceeding number of movie id than actual id.

I only want it to match the missing user_id with the existing one and not exceed 69878.
For example, the the number ***75167*** will become the last number of unique user id which is ***69878*** and the movie id ***65133*** will become ***10677*** the last unique movie id.

Actual

```
    user_id movie_id    rating  timestamp
0   1   122 5.0 838985046
1   1   185 5.0 838983525
2   1   231 5.0 838983392
3   1   292 5.0 838983421
4   1   316 5.0 838983392
... ... ... ... ...
10000044    71567   1984    1.0 912580553
10000045    71567   1985    1.0 912580553
10000046    71567   1986    1.0 912580553
10000047    71567   2012    3.0 912580722
10000048    71567   2028    5.0 912580344
```

Desired

```
user_id movie_id    rating  timestamp
0   1   122 5.0 838985046
1   1   185 5.0 838983525
2   1   231 5.0 838983392
3   1   292 5.0 838983421
4   1   316 5.0 838983392
... ... ... ... ...
10000044    69878   1984    1.0 912580553
10000045    69878   1985    1.0 912580553
10000046    69878   1986    1.0 912580553
10000047    69878   2012    3.0 912580722
10000048    69878   2028    5.0 912580344
```

Is there anyway to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this:

```py
df2 = df.groupby('user_id').count().reset_index()
df2 = df2.assign(new_user_id=df2.index + 1).set_index('user_id')
df = df.join(df2['new_user_id'], on='user_id').drop(columns=['user_id']).rename(columns={'new_user_id':'user_id'})

df2 = df.groupby('movie_id').count().reset_index()
df2 = df2.assign(new_movie_id=df2.index + 1).set_index('movie_id')
df = df.join(df2['new_movie_id'], on='movie_id').drop(columns=['movie_id']).rename(columns={'new_movie_id':'movie_id'})

df = pd.concat([df[['user_id', 'movie_id']], df.drop(columns=['user_id', 'movie_id'])], axis=1)
```

Sample input:

```
   user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
0        1         2     5.0  838985046
1        1         4     5.0  838983525
2        3         4     5.0  838983392
3        3         6     5.0  912580553
4        5         2     5.0  912580722
5        5         6     5.0  912580344
```

Sample output:

```
   user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
0        1         1     5.0  838985046
1        1         2     5.0  838983525
2        2         2     5.0  838983392
3        2         3     5.0  912580553
4        3         1     5.0  912580722
5        3         3     5.0  912580344
```

---

Here are intermediate results and explanations.

First we do this:

```py
df2 = df.groupby('user_id').count().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
0        1         2       2          2
1        3         2       2          2
2        5         2       2          2
```

What we have done above is to use `groupby` to get one row per unique user_id. We call `count` just to convert the output (a groupby object) back to a dataframe. We call `reset_index` to create a new integer range index with no gaps. (NOTE: the only column we care about for future use is user_id.)

Next we do this:

```py
df2 = df2.assign(new_user_id=df2.index + 1).set_index('user_id')
```

Output:

```
         movie_id  rating  timestamp  new_user_id
user_id
1               2       2          2            1
3               2       2          2            2
5               2       2          2            3
```

The `assign` call creates a new column named new_user_id which we fill using the 0 offset index plus 1 (so that we will not have id values < 1). The `set_index` call replaces our index with `user_id` in anticipation of using the index of this dataframe as the target for a late call to `join`.

The next step is:

```py
df = df.join(df2['new_user_id'], on='user_id').drop(columns=['user_id']).rename(columns={'new_user_id':'user_id'})
```

Output:

```
   movie_id  rating  timestamp  user_id
0         2     5.0  838985046        1
1         4     5.0  838983525        1
2         4     5.0  838983392        2
3         6     5.0  912580553        2
4         2     5.0  912580722        3
5         6     5.0  912580344        3
```

Here we have taken just the new_user_id column of df2 and called `join` on the df object, directing the method to use the user_id column (the `on` argument) in df to join with the index (which was originally the user_id column in df2). This creates a df with the desired new-paradigm user_id values in the column named new_user_id. All that remains is to drop the old-paradigm user_id column and rename new_user_id to be user_id, which is what the calls to `drop` and `rename` do.

The logic for changing the movie_id values to the new paradigm (i.e., eliminating gaps in the unique value set) is completely analogous. When we're done, we have this output:

```
   rating  timestamp  user_id  movie_id
0     5.0  838985046        1         1
1     5.0  838983525        1         2
2     5.0  838983392        2         2
3     5.0  912580553        2         3
4     5.0  912580722        3         1
5     5.0  912580344        3         3
```

To finish up, we reorder the columns to look like the original using this code:

```py
df = pd.concat([df[['user_id', 'movie_id']], df.drop(columns=['user_id', 'movie_id'])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
0        1         1     5.0  838985046
1        1         2     5.0  838983525
2        2         2     5.0  838983392
3        2         3     5.0  912580553
4        3         1     5.0  912580722
5        3         3     5.0  912580344
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is an alternative solution which uses `Series.unique()` instead of `gropuby` and saves a couple of lines:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.user_id.unique(), columns=['user_id']
    ).reset_index().set_index('user_id').rename(columns={'index':'new_user_id'})['new_user_id'] + 1
df = df.join(df2, on='user_id').drop(columns=['user_id']).rename(columns={'new_user_id':'user_id'})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.movie_id.unique(), columns=['movie_id']
    ).reset_index().set_index('movie_id').rename(columns={'index':'new_movie_id'})['new_movie_id'] + 1
df = df.join(df2, on='movie_id'
    ).drop(columns=['movie_id']).rename(columns={'new_movie_id':'movie_id'})

df = pd.concat([df[['user_id', 'movie_id']], df.drop(columns=['user_id', 'movie_id'])], axis=1)
```

The idea here is:

Line 1:

- use `unique` to get the unique values of user_id without bothering to count duplicates or maintain other columns (which is what `groupby` did in the original solution above)
- create a new dataframe containing these unique values in a column named new_user_id
- call `reset_index` to get an index that is a non-gapped integer range (one integer for each unique user_id)
- call `set_index` which will create a column named 'index' containing the previous index (0..number of unique user_id values) and make user_id the new index
- rename the column labeled 'index' to be named new_user_id
- access the new_user_id column and add 1 to convert from 0-offset to 1-offset id value.

Line 2:

- call `join` just as we did in the original solution, except that the `other` dataframe is simply df2 (which is fine since it has only a single column, new_user_id).

The logic for movie_id is completely analogous, and the final line using `concat` is the same as in the original solution above.

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you please elaborate on how it works?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer with a detailed explanation.